# UPS Rate Request Access Denied

Tags: html, ajax, ups

the below script is a simple XML rate request to UPS and it works on my local PC via IE but not Chrome.  When I moved over to my iis web server (workgroup member) it continually fails with:

> Origin https://www..com not found in
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. XMLHttpRequest: Network Error
>   0x80070005, Access is denied.

I thought this would be a simple fix with all the CORS searching however, I have had zero luck with all my efforts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how I can get this to work on the web server.

Much of the data and credentials have been change to protect personal information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<script language="javascript">
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
    var xmlRequest = "<this will contain a well formatted XML to UPS that was proved to work";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        XMLHttpRequestObject.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
    }

    function getRates()
    {
        var xmlResponse;
        var ratedShipment;

        if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            var obj = document.getElementById('targetDiv');
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate", true);

            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
                {
                    xmlResponse = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML; 
                    displayRates(xmlResponse);              
                }
            }

            XMLHttpRequestObject.send(xmlRequest);
        }
    }

    function displayRates(argXML)
    {
        // Will display rates in html table
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't just dump a mountain of code here and expect us to figure it out. Why do you think the host component is omitted in the error?

Comment: Last time i posted I got yelled at for not having the code.  You people here are never happy!

Comment: The expectations are a [minimal, well-defined example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where anything not related to the problem is removed. There's such a thing as too much information, as well as too little.